# How to hide fields in order_line based on some value of their parent (order_id) in Odoo v16?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Is there any way to hide some fields in purchase order line based on some conditions/value of their parent (order_id). I've tried this way:

```
<field name="price_subtotal" attrs="{'invisible': [('order_id.currency_id.name', '=', 'IDR')]}"/>
```

But unfortunately, this one only works with Odoo v7 and lower. I use v16 by the way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For invisibility on parent conditions you can use `column_invisible` with `parent` as the parent of the relation.

But following example won't work, because you can only use one level of field depth on the parent.

```xml
<field name="price_subtotal"
    attrs="{'column_invisible': [('parent.currency_id.name', '=', 'IDR')]}" />
```

You can use `currency_id` (relation field) on `purchase.order.line` instead, because it is in the view anyways. But instead of using the name, go for the id in form of the external id:

```xml
<field name="price_subtotal"
    attrs="{'invisible': [('currency_id', '=', %(base.IDR)d)]}" />
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, and error:

KeyError: ('ir.model.data', <function IrModelData._xmlid_lookup at 0x7f34b0b52160>, "'base.IDR'")

Comment: Sorry my bad the xml id has to be without single quotation marks. edited it

Comment: Finally, I solved this one using your first suggestion. Although I didn't used your code 100%, but I really suggested by your explanation of "only use one level of field depth on the parent". So, instead, I create a new field to act as that 'one level' field named currency_name that related to currency_id.name and finally it solved. Thank you for your suggestion!